# Ease way for user permission function php

Tags: php, mysql

We want to add 4 types(or groups) of users to our website, they should access only associated pages what we allow while creating those groups. So should we set an array of permission and check at top of page if user has permission to view this page or any other way like creating db tables or writing class. Please help.

Comment: @jspcl we are trying to build something.

Answer (score 0):

Normally I'm not a big fan of using Zend outside of a fully **Zend** application, except with Zend_Lucene, but I would recommend using [Zend_Acl](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.acl.html) in your application, which handles this task transparently to your application. It's quite easy to use, here you have a sample code from the Zend dev:

```
$acl = new Zend_Acl();

$acl->addRole(new Zend_Acl_Role('guest'))
    ->addRole(new Zend_Acl_Role('member'))
    ->addRole(new Zend_Acl_Role('admin'));

$parents = array('guest', 'member', 'admin');

$acl->addRole(new Zend_Acl_Role('someUser'), $parents);
$acl->add(new Zend_Acl_Resource('someResource'));
$acl->deny('guest', 'someResource');
$acl->allow('member', 'someResource');

echo $acl->isAllowed('someUser', 'someResource') ? 'allowed' : 'denied';
```

Hope I can help,
David

Comment: can you tell me how to use it if i am not using zend framework for my website.

Answer (score 0):

What I have to solve this issue is this:

1. I have created one table with user levels.
2. Every time the user logs in, I retrieve this level from the database and save it in session variables.
3. In every page,  I check if the value of the session variable that correspond to the user is allowed to see this page.

**EDIT**: tO check, I used this function:

```
function checkPermission($allowedLevel)
{
 if(isset($_SESSION['level']) AND ($_SESSION['level'] == "$allowedLevel")){
  return TRUE;
 }
 else{
  return FALSE;
 }
}
```

And in the top of every script  I have:

```
if(checkPermission($someLevel)){
 // Run the script
}
else{
 // Manage unauthorized access...
}
```

**EDIT 2:** My tables are like this:
I have a table for levels: `user_type(id_level, level)` and in the table where I store the user information I have a foreign key to the `id_level` for each user.

Every time they log in, I get the user information by making a join between the table `user` and `user_type` (Since `id_level` is a foreign key in my `user` table)

Comment: so what function will you use at every page?

Comment: thanks, can you even let me know table structure for user labels, and what sql query would you use. Thanks for your best support.

Comment: ok got it, what if we allow any page for 3 groups so how yours function would work in that case for example, we want to allow admin, executives to view add customer page. so how this function would work in that case.

Comment: @seoppc: You just have to add all the levels you want to allow when you check in every page: `if(checkPermission($someLevel1) OR checkPermission($someLevel2)){ //...`

Comment: what do you think about David Conde answer btw?

Answer (score 0):

I created 2 tables:

1) Users (ID, Name, Password, GroupID)

2) UserGroups (ID, Name)

Then build a function which checks if the user is in a group. On the top of the page you check this and show the page (or not).

If you want to extend this you can create a table actions and a crosstable, which links an action (access a page or edit something) to a set of usergroups. This way you can have multiple groups on one action. These are those tables:

3) Actions (ID, Name)

4) Group_actions (GroupID, ActionID)

Comment: can you even submit php code, how to check if user has permission for page.